Confused about Birefringence

In the picture, the second one is normal figure in textbook, but how to understand the first figure, when the light incident along the normal to the surface, when the ordinary wave also
divergent? why? what is the point?
Your help would be highly appreciated!

The first figure does not look right. Where did you get it?

https://www.microscopyu.com/techniques/polarized-light/principles-of-birefringence

https://www.olympus-lifescience.com/de/microscope-resource/primer/java/polarizedlight/crystalwavefronts/

I've never seen such ordinary wave behavior. Furthermore, the figure 2 of your 1st link does agree with the right picture you've posted.
